# 2D-Visibility/Light - Efficient Polygon-Ray intersection

Tags: c++, polygon, sfml, raytracing, line-intersection

Im trying to write a game in 2D with Sfml. For that game i need a Lightengine and some code that can give me the area of the world that is visible to the player. AS both problems fit very well together (are pratically the same) i would like to solve both problems at once.
My world will be loaded from files in which the hitboxes of objects will be represented as Polygons. 
I now wrote some code that takes a list of Polygons and the Direction of a Ray that follows the mouse and finds the closest intersection with any of these polygons.
The next step now would be to cast rays from the players or lights Position towards the edges of the polygons, aswell rays offset by +-0.000001 radians to determine the visible area and give it back as a polygon.

The Problem though is that my algorithm (it calculates the inersection between two lines with vector mathematics) is too slow.
In my very good PC i get 100fps with 300 egdes and one Ray.

I now read many articles online but couldnt find one best solution. But as far as i read it should be much faster to calculate intersections with triangles.

My question now: would it be meaningly faster to triangulate the polygons once while loading the map and then use ray-triangle intersection or is there any better way that you know of to solve my problem? 
I also heard of bounding Volumen hierachies but i dont know howmuch impact that would have.

Im a bit surprised of how much power my algorithm consumes, as it only has to calculate some 2 dimensional intersections...

Comment: might want to ask this question at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok i will thank you for your hint :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone looking for the solution I finally went with:

I discovered the Box2D Physics Engine and I am now using the b2World::RayCast(...) function to determine whether and where a ray hits an object in my scene.
For now everything works fine and smooth (did no exact benchmark yet) :)
http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/world-querying
I got it to work with the help of this site
Have a nice Day! :)